# ScrollView not Scrolling with GridLayout

Tags: python, kivy

I Have browsed the web for 30 minutes looking for a solution for this problem but none of the examples on the web worked. I have tried custom heights in the GridLayout and played around with various values that other people used in the web but none of them worked. I also tried to run the code of the ScrollView in another file with only this code but the scrolling still didn't work.
The .py file is not relevant here i think because i have no code in there for this section of my program. If you still need it or need more of my kv file i will post it just send me a message thank you :)

kv:

```
<TrainingPlans>
    name: "trainingplans"

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .85
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": .15}
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        GridLayout:
            size: (root.width, root.height)
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_Y: None
            cols: 2
            height: self.minimum_height
            row_default_height: 150
            row_force_default: True

            Label:
                text: "training1"

            Button:
                size_hint: .3, 1
                background_normal: "training_programs/unknown.jpeg"

            Label:
                text: "training2"

            Button:
                size_hint: .3, 1
                background_normal: "training_programs/unknown.jpeg"

            Label:
                text: "training3"

            Button:
                size_hint: .3, 1
                background_normal: "training_programs/unknown.jpeg"

            Label:
                text: "training4"

            Button:
                size_hint: .3, 1
                background_normal: "training_programs/unknown.jpeg"

            Label:
                text: "training5"

            Button:
                size_hint: .3, 1
                background_normal: "training_programs/unknown.jpeg"

            Label:
                text: "training6"

            Button:
                size_hint: .3, 1
                background_normal: "training_programs/unknown.jpeg"

            Label:
                text: "training7"

            Button:
                size_hint: .3, 1
                background_normal: "training_programs/unknown.jpeg"

            Label:
                text: "training8"

            Button:
                size_hint: .3, 1
                background_normal: "training_programs/unknown.jpeg"


            Label:
                text: "training9"

            Button:
                size_hint: .3, 1
                background_normal: "training_programs/unknown.jpeg"

    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .15

        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: .3, .8
            pos_hint: {"x": .01, "y": .06}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "mainwindow"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo. Change:

```
size_hint_Y: None
```

to

```
size_hint_y: None
```

in your `GridLayout` rule in the `kv`.

Comment: wow i think i have literally looked over it 100 times and didn't see that... Thank you so much!